# How to have Appium install a fresh app only on the first test, then reused app + data for subsequent tests while in the same session

Tags: ios, appium

I am testing an iOS app using [Appium](http://appium.io). On a test session, running multiple test cases, I would like to:

- Install the app onto the simulator at the beginning of the session
- Reuse that same app + the any data it retains during subsequent tests

The [`fullReset` and `noReset` capabilities](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/reset-strategies.md) seem to have something to do with this but it makes no sense to me what I should set these (or something else) to in order to get the effect I'm looking for.

Can someone help?

Comment: Set flag fullReset = True if u want to reset app evey time  and noReset = True if u want to retain your data of the app in desired capabilities

Comment: desired_caps['noReset'] = True